# Date comparison failing SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure which takes a single `date` input.

First I want to do a simple select in the stored procedure based on the date with which the procedure is executed. The select query works well when I hardcode the date, but when I replace the date with the paramter  variable I don't get any data. The same happens later in the procedure when I modify the date with the `DATEADD()` function and use it again for comparison.

Below is the first SELECT-->

```
select
    (case when act.Sense = 'C' then act.AmountAccCur else -1*act.AmountAccCur end) as In_mvmnt_FTE,
    recon.account_Id as in_Account_Id  
FROM ktpplus..Accounting act 
JOIN Kustom..T_RECON recon on act.Account_Id=recon.account_Id
    and act.ValueDate = @p_execdate
```

LATER in the procedure I modify and use the parameter as

```
insert  into recon_daily 
 select @p_execdate Fecha,
c1.Empresa, c1.Clasificación, 
c1.Clas_de_Emisor,
c1.Moneda,
c1.Cuenta_Contable,
c1.Tipo_de_Cuenta,
c1.Saldo_Total Saldo, -- in saldo we take saldo total from last day
mvt.In_mvmnt_FTE Movimiento_FTE,c1.account_Id, 
(c1.Saldo + mvt.In_mvmnt_FTE) Saldo_Total

from 
T_RECON c1 left  join #update_mvmnt_fte_calculated mvt
on
c1.Fecha=DATEADD(day,-1,@p_execdate)
```

Comment: Show the definition of the parameter `@p_execdate` and how you are calling it. We can't guess.

Comment: DEF-->proc recon(@p_execdate date)
called like recon '08/03/2022'
date is stored in db in the format: 2022-03-08

Comment: Is it really a date, or is it a varchar pretending to be a date? Because SQL Server's date format is **NOT** `2022-03-08`. It's actually a **binary** format that is not human readable, and when you see different it's just your query or reporting tool being helpful.

Comment: Also, if you call it using `'08/03/2022'`, you're calling it **wrong**. Remember, different languages and cultures have their own expectations around dates, with different conventions around ordering and separators. Some languages tend to `MM/dd/yyyy`, while others might prefer `dd-MM-yyyy`. The SQL language is no different. It is its own language, and even though it's just a programing language it still has its own preferred date formats (`yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`) and anything else is **INCORRECT** for that language.

Comment: in the database column  is built as datetime,thank you

Comment: an you suggest how to compare datetime with this I tried using,convert(varchar,valuedate,103)=convert(varchar,@p_execdate,103),which failed with error of overflow,I canot change the procedure call to any other format of date as its called implicity by the application and I have no access to code that executes the procedure ,I can only see how its being called in logs

Comment: It is a datetime in your database but what are the values in your table? You are passing in a string literal which will convert to a date with midnight time portion. If you have the time portion in your data this query will never work. You would need to convert that column to a date for your query to work. Or do a range check with your parameter.

Comment: This is why providing sample data would go a long way to letting others know how to help you.

Comment: If it is being called with string literals there may be some issues. The application needs to be fixed.

Comment: IN system DB valuedate-->
2021-01-02 00:00:00.000

Comment: We need a [mre] e.g. DBFiddle in order to assist.

Comment: If it's a `datetime` column in the database that means "date with time." So if you're expecting `'08/03/2022'` to equal March 8, 2022 it will only match rows that have the exact value, `'2022-03-08T00:00:00.000'`, and it won't match `'2022-03-08T00:00:00.003'` or any other time on the day. If you want to match any time on the day you're going to have to match the range `>= '2022-03-08T00:00:00.000'` and `< '2022-03-09T00:00:00.000'` which will involve some math with your `@p_execdate` parameter.

Comment: The only string format to feed a value into a datetime column or variable that works in any parameterization  is the small SQL ISO format wich is: "YYYYMMDD" any other format like 'MM/DD/YYYY" is subject to caution, because it depends about session parameter resulting from language settings... Also, a DATETIME has a time part as @AlwaysLearning says....